# how to check UIControl class orientation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, xcode4

In my app i have created one custom class with superclass UIControl.and add that class view to  window.Now my problem is my custom class view cannot identify the orientation.when i rotate the device custom class view doesnt rotate.

Is there any method to rotate a custom class or is there any way to rotate that custom view?

here is my code:

```
          - (void) showForView:(UIView *)forView
     {
        NSLog(@"window frame=%@",forView.window);
          if(self.hidden || hiding || !view.superview) {
                     UIWindow *viewWindow=[[UIWindow alloc]init]; 


               viewWindow = forView.window;


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CustomKeyboardWillShowNotification object:self];

    // remove from old view and add to new view (if necessary)
    if(view.superview && (view.superview != viewWindow)) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if(!view.superview) {
        CGFloat x;

             x = view.bounds.size.width / 2;

                   y = viewWindow.frame.size.height/2.5 + (view.frame.size.height/2);

        self.hiddenCenter = CGPointMake(x, y);
        view.center = hiddenCenter;

    self.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-(M_PI/2));

        [viewWindow addSubview:view];
            self.autoHideWhenInactive = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kKeyboardAutoHideKey];
    }
}
```

Please guide me or suggest me the way to do this.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post some code of your Custom class view? As we may not be able to help you out without looking at your code. Also please do post what is the purpose to subclass UIControl?

Comment: I have added custom keyboard in my custom class view and then add that view to window.

Comment: Also try rotating the custom view by putting it inside a viewController not the window. And setting ViewController's `-(BOOL)shoudAutoRotateInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` to return YES.

Comment: Ok Shweta, thanks for posting your code, my question is where do you call `-(void) showForView:(UIView *)forView` from?

Comment: Thanks for help Its a InputField class when inputfield comes in the  view it shows the custom keyboard class.so i called this method from UIVIewController class.And forView is the custom Inputfield class view.

Comment: I think the approach you are taking is a bit different. Also you need to rotate the custom keyboard by checking the orientation of the viewController under `- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` and based on that rotate or transform your custom keyboard. Hope you understand. If you require more help then do let me know

Answer (score 1):

you need to add your custom view to a view controller.view, not to Window:
windows don't rotate...

Answer (score 0):

Tried this?.`[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation`

Comment: This fetches you orientation of status bar but doesn't rotate the view.

Comment: if you know the orientation you can rotate on your own.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.can u please put some sample code.

Comment: @ParthBhatt. Its good know that you have modified Zxing. But Windows won't rotate automatically. You will have to do it by yourself.

Comment: @ShwetaThakar. To detect orientation change you can add Orientation notifiation and check orientation make changes accordingly.